# Java: Get unique values in large solr response

Tags: java, json, parsing, testing, solr

I'm a tester and I have a HUGE Solr documents.

I can view in either XML or JSon, but I've chosen JSON

I'm trying to get see how many unique strings there are in a given field.

```
 {    "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
        "wt": "json",
        "q": "lr_listing_status_search:pending"
    }
},
"response": {
    "numFound": 21410,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
        {
            "m_document_id_exact": "1428937575-565899144",
            "lr_master_listing_id": 565899144,
            "lr_baths": 2,
            "lr_beds": 2,
            "lr_whole_baths": 2,
            "lr_listing_status": ["Pending Continue To Show"],
```

I have Java code to using org.json to put it into a JSON Object

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
        JSONObject response = readJsonFromUrl("http://sdsitgn.solr-aprop1.admin.inf:8086/solr/core0/select/?q=lr_listing_status_search:pending&wt=json");
        System.out.println(response.toString());
```

For example there are 10,000 solr docs with this lr_listing_status field.

I want to know see all uniques for example
"Pending Continue To Show"
"Pending"
"Pending with Contingencies"

Maybe there's a better way? Solrj maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a copyField to copy lr_listing_status to lr_listing_status_facet, and use KeywordAnalyzer in that field (well, add whatever needs to be added to take care of case normalization etc if it needs to be done too).

Then you can get what you want by adding a facet on lr_listing_status_facet, by adding this to your request: &facet=true&facet.field=lr_listing_status_facet

Look at [faceting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters) for all features it provides.